# Solving $ \int \sqrt{1 + \tan(x)}\:dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I know this is lazy, but I was really hoping that someone could read over my work on this integral and let me know whether I've made any errors.

Here I will address the integral:
\begin{equation}
    I = \int \sqrt{1 + \tan(x)}\:dx \nonumber
\end{equation}
Here let $u = \tan(x)$:
\begin{equation}
    I = \int \sqrt{u + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{u^2 + 1}\:du = \int \frac{\sqrt{u + 1}}{u^2 + 1}\:du \nonumber 
\end{equation}
Let $t^2 = u + 1$:
\begin{equation}
    I = \int \frac{\left|t\right|}{\left(t^2 - 1\right)^2 + 1} \cdot 2t \:dt = 2 \int \frac{t\left|t\right|}{t^4 - 2t^2 + 2}\:dt = 2 \int \frac{t\left|t\right|}{\left(t^2 + t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2} \right)\left(t^2 - t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2} \right)}\:dt \nonumber
\end{equation}
Now:
\begin{equation}
    \tan(x) + 1 \geq 0 \rightarrow u + 1 \geq 0 \rightarrow t^2 \geq 0 \nonumber
\end{equation}
Which implies that $t$ can be both positive and negative. Thankfully the solution to one is merely the negative of the other. Here we proceed with the case $t > 0$:
\begin{align}
    I &= 2 \int \frac{t^2}{\left(t^2 + t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2} \right)\left(t^2 - t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2} \right)}\:dt \nonumber \\
    &= 2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}} \int \left[\frac{t}{t^2 - t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{t}{t^2 + t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}}\right]\:dt \nonumber \\
     &= 2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}} \int \left[\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{2t - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}{t^2 - t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}} -\frac{1}{2}\cdot  \frac{2t + \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}{t^2 + t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}}\right]\:dt \nonumber \\
     &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}  \bigg[ \int \frac{2t - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} }{t^2 - t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}}\:dt + \int \frac{ \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}{t^2 - t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}}\:dt \nonumber \\
     &\quad-\int \frac{2t + \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} }{t^2 + t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}}\:dt + \int \frac{ \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}{t^2 + t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}}\:dt \bigg] \nonumber \\
     &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}  \bigg[ \int \frac{2t - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} }{t^2 - t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}}\:dt + \int \frac{ \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}{\left(t - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}\right)^2 + \sqrt{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{2}}\:dt \nonumber \\
     &\quad-\int \frac{2t + \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} }{t^2 + t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}}\:dt + \int \frac{ \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}{ \left(t + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}\right)^2 + \sqrt{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{2}}\:dt \bigg] \nonumber \\
     &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}  \bigg[\ln\left|t^2 - t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}\right| + \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{2}}}\arctan\left( \frac{t - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{2}}}\right) \nonumber  \\
     &\quad+ \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{2}}}\arctan\left( \frac{t + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{2}}}\right)- \ln\left|t^2 + t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}\right|  \bigg] + C \nonumber \\
     &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}\ln\left| \frac{t^2 - t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}}{t^2 + t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}} \right| \nonumber \\
     &\qquad+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{2}}}\bigg[\arctan\left( \frac{t - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{2}}}\right) + \arctan\left( \frac{t + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{2}}}\right)\bigg] + C \nonumber \\
     &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}\ln\left| \frac{t^2 - t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}}{t^2 + t\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1} + \sqrt{2}} \right| \nonumber \\
     &\qquad+ \sqrt{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2} - 1}}\bigg[\arctan\left( \frac{\sqrt{2}t - \sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} - 1}}\right) + \arctan\left( \frac{\sqrt{2}t + \sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} - 1}}\right)\bigg] + C \nonumber
\end{align}
Where $C$ is the constant of integration and $t^2 = \tan(x) + 1$

Comment: Follow the same steps, as seen here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3230051/515527

Answer (score 4):

I know why you don't want to go over that again. :)

Why don't you instead make the substitution $$1+\tan x=u^2,$$ to obtain $$2\int{\frac{u^2}{1+(u^2-1)^2}\mathrm d u},$$ which may be easily done by parts, as follows, for example, $$u\int{\frac{2u}{1+(u^2-1)^2}\mathrm d u}-\int\cdots,$$ where the integral in the first summand is easy to do by using the substitution $u^2-1=y.$ This reduces the problem to dealing only with the second summand.

Comment: I think that you lost a $1$ in denominator.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That's true. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there should be lonely $u$ *infront* of the integral.

Comment: @mrtaurho Why not? It's just one suggested way to integrate *by parts.*

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment.*

You could have done it faster using
$$\sqrt{1 + \tan(x)}=t \implies x=-\tan ^{-1}\left(1-t^2\right)\implies dx=\frac{2 t}{1+\left(1-t^2\right)^2} \,dt$$ making
$$I=\int \sqrt{1 + \tan(x)}\,dx=\int \frac{2 t^2}{1+\left(1-t^2\right)^2} \,dt$$ Using now
$$1+\left(1-t^2\right)^2=(t^2-(1-i))(t^2-(1+i))$$
and using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{2 t^2}{1+\left(1-t^2\right)^2}=\frac{1+i}{t^2-(1-i)}+\frac{1-i}{t^2-(1+i)}$$ and then
$$I=2 \left(-\frac{\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{-1-i}}\right)}{(-1-i)^{3/2}}-\frac{\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{-1+i}}\right)}{(-1+i)^{3/2}}\right)$$ Using later
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-1-i}}=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{2}}+i\frac{ \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{2}} \implies \frac 1{(-1-i)^{3/2}}=\frac{1+i}8$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-1+i}}=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{2}}-i\frac{ \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{2}} \implies \frac 1{(-1+i)^{3/2}}=\frac{1-i}8$$

Comment: Indeed, I took a 'real based approach' - very often (as we see with your solution) it's often the more intensive approach.

Answer (score 2):

Let  $1+\tan x= \sqrt2 t^2 $  in
$$I=\int\sqrt{1+\tan x}\;dx,\>\>\>\>\> J=\int\frac1{\sqrt{1+\tan x}}\;dx
$$
and integrate
\begin{align}
I+\sqrt2 J
= &\ 2^{3/4}
\int \frac{t^2+1}{t^4-\sqrt2 t^2 +1 }dt
=\frac{2^{3/4}}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}
\tan^{-1}\frac{t-\frac1t}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}\\
I-\sqrt2 J
= &\ 2^{3/4}
\int \frac{t^2-1}{t^2-\sqrt2t^2+1}dt
=-\frac{2^{3/4}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}
\coth^{-1}\frac{t+\frac1t}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Writing $\cos$/$\sin$ of $\frac\pi8$ might make the result look a little prettier, but (+1) all the same. Cheers