# How to integrate $\sqrt{1+\tan(2x)}dx$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate $$\int \sqrt{1+\tan(2x)}dx$$
I am trying this question using the formula of $\tan(2x)$. Now, $\tan(2x)=\frac{2\tan{x}}{1-\tan^{2}x}$.

So, if I put this formula of $\tan(2x)$ on the above integral, then the integral will be $$\int \sqrt{\frac{1-\tan^{2}x+2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^{2}x}}dx$$.

Now I am thinking of writing the numerator as $(1+\tan{x})^{2}-2\tan^{2}x$.

So, the above integral will become $$\int \sqrt{\frac{(1+\tan{x})^{2}-2\tan^{2}x}{1-\tan^{2}x}}dx$$.

Now after this step we can write the integral as $$\int \sqrt{\frac{1+\tan{x}}{1-\tan{x}}-\frac{2\tan^{2}x}{1-\tan^{2}x}}dx$$.

But after this step, I can't approach further. So, please help me out.

Comment: Please put a backslash in front of each `tan`, with a space in each `tanx`. Substitute $y=\sqrt{1+\tan x}$.

Comment: Sorry, $y=\sqrt{1+\tan2x}$.

Comment: This is a nice integral !

Comment: Here are some similar questions: [Solving $ \int \sqrt{1 + \tan(x)}\:dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3331669/solving-int-sqrt1-tanx-dx), [How to evaluate $\int\sqrt{1-\tan x} \,dx$ without using up paper?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229336/how-to-evaluate-int-sqrt1-tan-x-dx-without-using-up-paper).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving $ \int \sqrt{1 + \tan(x)}\:dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3331669/solving-int-sqrt1-tanx-dx) Note you can use the substitution of $u = 2x$ to get $\frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{1+\tan(u)}du$, i.e., half of the integral asked about in the duplicate question.

Comment: I also felt in the trap ! $2$ is a $\color{red}{\text{red herring}}$ !

Answer (score 7):

If you use $x=\tan^{-1}(t)$, the integral becomes
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{2 t}{t^2-1}}}{t^2+1}\,dt$$ Now, for one of the roots, chose
$$ \sqrt{1-\frac{2 t}{t^2-1}}=u\implies t=  \frac{\sqrt{u^4-2 u^2+2}-1}{u^2-1}$$ Assume $u>0$ to make
$$I=\int \frac{u^2}{u^4-2 u^2+2}\,du$$

Use now
$$u^4-2 u^2+2=\big(u^2 -(1-i)\big)\big(u^2 -(1+i)\big)$$ Partial fraction decomposition $\cdots$

**Edit**

$2$ is a $\color{red}{\text{red herring}}$ !

Consider
$$I=\int\sqrt{1+\tan(ax)}\,dx$$
$$\sqrt{1+\tan(ax)}=u \implies x=-\frac{1}{a}\tan ^{-1}\left(1-u^2\right)\implies$$ $$ dx=\frac{2 u}{a \left(\left(1-u^2\right)^2+1\right)}\,du$$
$$I=\frac 2a \int \frac  {u^2}{u^4-2 u^2+2 } \,du$$

Make it more general
$$J=\int (1+\tan (a x))^{\frac{1}{n}}\,dx$$
$$J=\frac n a \int \frac {u^n}{u^{2 n}-2 u^n+2 }\,du=\frac n a \int \frac {u^n}{\big(u^n -(1-i)\big)\big(u^n -(1+i)\big) }\,du$$

$$ J=\frac n {2a} \int \Bigg(\frac{1+i}{u^n-(1-i)}+\frac{1-i}{u^n-(1+i)}    \Bigg)\,du$$

$$K=\int \frac {du}{u^n+\alpha}=\frac{u }{\alpha }\,\,
   _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{n};\frac{n+1}{n};-\frac{u^n}{\alpha
   }\right)$$